# How can I execute certain part of code from a reaction on a private message (not a channel message) with Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a Discord bot that sends private welcome messages to users that enter my server.

[image: My Discord bot private message screen]

I want to execute some lines of code (I want to add different roles to the users) which differ if the user reacts with those three emojis.
Online I found guides that refer to channel messages only and I don't understand which approach to use with private messages.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach for private messages should be the same as channel messages.

```js
// Create a reaction filter that only will collect those three emojis
const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)

// Create reaction collector (message is the message the bot sent).
// The time is the time in milliseconds that the collector should run for
// (i.e. how long the user has to react).
// Discord.js v12:
// const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 15000})
// Discord.js v13:
const collector = message.createReactionCollector({filter, time: 15000})

// Fired when the user reacts
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  switch (reaction.name) {
    case '':
      message.reply('you chose Italian!')
      break
    case '':
      message.reply('you chose English!')
      break
    case '':
      message.reply('you have a secret code!')
  }
})
```

For more information see [the Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016011207/https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors)).